# Can I report values from one field using another as a reference point in the same table?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

My report returns a default of;

"My cat is Fat and Lazy"

```
Field_1           Field_2 
========          ========
1                  Sleek        
2                 Athletic
```

However I want to replace 'Fat' with 'Sleek' and 'Lazy' with 'Athletic'

So the final string will read ;

"My cat is Sleek and Athletic"

My question is this, can I make the report pick up (via a formula) that if Field_1 = 1 to replace Fat with 'Sleek'?

Field_1 is static but Field_2 is dynamic and the values will change on depending on the data.

Comment: Is this motivated by some intrinsic desire?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're pulling the data you could do this in a couple of ways:

In the SQL add a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN field_1 = 1 THEN 'sleek' ELSE field_2 END AS modified_field_2
```

In a formula field (Crystal syntax used in example):

```
if { table_name.field_1 } = 1 then 'sleek' else { table_name.field_2 }
```

---

Edit:

Please see the following link for an example of how to join a table to itself (a self-join) in order to "link" the two records to get the full sentence: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59566/16

Comment: So would I need to reference the table as well e.g. if {table.name}{ field_1 } = 1 then 'sleek' else { field_2 }?

Comment: Right. Depending on how your report is set up. If you have tables, then yes add the table name with a `.` before the field name. I'll update the answer in a second.

Comment: Thanks bernie, I'm a novice when it comes to crystal, can I really push my luck and ask what the code is for the complete sentance?  
 
Is this motivated by some intrinsic desire? Nope best shortest example I could think of.. besides one of our cats is really fat anyway

Comment: The full code involves more than just a formula. Because you need to somehow "link" the two records. When attempting to "link" to records in the same table a self-join is pretty much the only game in town. I will add a link to an example of how to perform a self-join. You may need to put on your SQL Thinking Cap for this one.

Comment: It's a biggy! That'll keep me busy tomorrow at work. I tried to do a multiple replace - it nearly worked, but I'll give your solution a go.